# How to export extended (master) public key from MetaMask

Tags: wallets, metamask, addresses, public-key, hd-wallets

I want to export **extended public key** for watch-only access to all ethereum addresses in the MetaMask HD wallet at once. It's very usefull for tracking of all portfolio/wallets in one place, especially when there are many HD addresses.

Is it possible with MetaMask? How I can do it?